# Why do I have to submit 2 times in a form in react to send data in backend? First time its going empty and then second time its sending values I gave

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, fetch, form-submit

I am making a register page in react. I am sending my data from React to Express but I have to click Submit button twice to send the data. I don't understand why it's happening like that. I tried with both fetch and axios method but same thing happened. I even made my own custom hook and tried but still it was the same.
Here is the Code.

Login.js

```
import react, { useState } from "react";
import "./Login.css";
import useInput from "../Hooks/use-input";
import axios from "axios";

const Login = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      fullname: undefined,
      email: undefined,
      password: undefined,
      dob: undefined,
      gender: undefined,
    },
  ]);

  const [enteredFullName, setenteredFullName] = useState("");
  const [enteredemail, setenteredemail] = useState("");
  const [enteredPassword, setenteredPassword] = useState("");
  const [enteredDob, setenteredDob] = useState("");
  const [enteredGender, setenteredGender] = useState("");
  const [isTocuhedFullName, setIsTouchedFullName] = useState(false);
  const [isTocuhedEmail, setIsTouchedEmail] = useState(false);
  const [isTocuhedPassword, setIsTouchedPassword] = useState(false);
  const [isTocuhedDob, setIsTouchedDob] = useState(false);
  const [isTocuhedGender, setIsTouchedGender] = useState(false);

  const fullNameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setenteredFullName(event.target.value);
  };
  const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setenteredemail(event.target.value);
  };
  const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setenteredPassword(event.target.value);
  };
  const dobChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setenteredDob(event.target.value);
  };
  const genderChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setenteredGender(event.target.value);
  };

  const fullNameBlurHandler = () => {
    setIsTouchedFullName(true);
  };
  const emailBlurHandler = () => {
    setIsTouchedEmail(true);
  };
  const passwordBlurHandler = () => {
    setIsTouchedPassword(true);
  };
  const dobBlurHandler = () => {
    setIsTouchedDob(true);
  };
  const genderBlurHandler = () => {
    setIsTouchedGender(true);
  };

  // const {
  //   value: enteredFullName,
  //   isValid: enteredFullNameIsValid,
  //   hasError: fullNameHasError,
  //   valueChangeHandler: fullNameChangeHandler,
  //   inputBlurHandler: fullNameBlurHandler,
  //   reset: fullNameReset,
  // } = useInput((value) => value.trim() !== "");

  // const {
  //   value: enteredemail,
  //   isValid: enteredemailIsValid,
  //   hasError: emailHasError,
  //   valueChangeHandler: emailChangeHandler,
  //   inputBlurHandler: emailBlurHandler,
  //   reset: emailReset,
  // } = useInput((value) => value.includes("@"));

  // const {
  //   value: enteredPassword,
  //   isValid: enteredPasswordIsValid,
  //   hasError: passwordHasError,
  //   valueChangeHandler: passwordChangeHandler,
  //   inputBlurHandler: passwordBlurHandler,
  //   reset: passwordReset,
  // } = useInput((value) => value.length >= 8);

  // const {
  //   value: enteredDob,
  //   isValid: enteredDobIsValid,
  //   hasError: dobHasError,
  //   valueChangeHandler: dobChangeHandler,
  //   inputBlurHandler: dobBlurHandler,
  //   reset: dobReset,
  // } = useInput((value) => value.trim() !== "");

  // const {
  //   value: enteredGender,
  //   isValid: enteredGenderIsValid,
  //   hasError: GenderHasError,
  //   valueChangeHandler: genderChangeHandler,
  //   inputBlurHandler: genderBlurHandler,
  //   reset: genderReset,
  // } = useInput((value) => value !== "None");

  // let formisValid = false;

  // formisValid =
  //   enteredFullNameIsValid &&
  //   enteredemailIsValid &&
  //   enteredPasswordIsValid &&
  //   enteredDobIsValid &&
  //   enteredGenderIsValid;

  const formSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let enteredFullNameIsValid;
    setData([
      {
        fullname: enteredFullName,
        email: enteredemail,
        password: enteredPassword,
        dob: enteredDob,
        gender: enteredGender,
      },
    ]);
    console.log(data);
    // setData(prev => ({
    //   ...prev, fullname: enteredFullName,
    // }))
    // console.log(data);
    // const res = await (
    //   await fetch("/register?data=" + JSON.stringify(data), {
    //     method: "POST",
    //   })
    // ).json();

    // const res = await axios
    //   .post("/register?data=" + JSON.stringify(data))
    //   .then((res) => res.data)
    //   .catch((err) => err.response.data);

    // fullNameReset();
    // emailReset();
    // passwordReset();
    // dobReset();
    // genderReset();

    setenteredFullName("");
    setenteredPassword("");
  };

  return (
    <form className="container" onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className="heading">Register Page</div>
      <div className="details">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Full Name"
            value={enteredFullName}
            onChange={fullNameChangeHandler}
            onBlur={fullNameBlurHandler}
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>E-mail</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            value={enteredemail}
            onChange={emailChangeHandler}
            onBlur={emailBlurHandler}
            placeholder="E-mail"
            id="email"
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            value={enteredPassword}
            onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
            onBlur={passwordBlurHandler}
            placeholder="Password"
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Date of Birth</label>
          <input
            value={enteredDob}
            onChange={dobChangeHandler}
            onBlur={dobBlurHandler}
            type="date"
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Gender</label>
          <select
            value={enteredGender}
            onChange={genderChangeHandler}
            onBlur={genderBlurHandler}
          >
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the state of your form inputs incorrectly. You are setting the state of each input to the empty string when the form is first rendered, and then you are setting the state of each input to the value of the corresponding form field when the user types in the field.

Instead, you should initialize the state of each input to the empty string, and then set the state of the input to the value of the form field when the user types in the field.

For example, for the full name field, you would do the following:

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");

const fullNameChangeHandler = (event) => {
  setFullName(event.target.value);
};
```

This way, when the form is first rendered, the state of the full name field will be an empty string, and when the user types in the field, the state of the full name field will be set to the value of the field.